# Shorter way to write if statement with multiple OR conditions?

Tags: javascript

I am writing a function that inserts values into a database.

I am checking to make sure that all fields are filled out by the user before the form is submitted.

If not, a message is displayed saying to fill out all fields.

```
if (!req.query.itemCode || !req.query.itemCode || !req.query.totalQuantity || !req.query.availableQuantity || !req.query.quantityRequested || !req.query.requestor || !req.query.projectNum || !req.query.projectDetails) return
```

You can see that with 5+ values, it quickly turns into a big if statement

Thanks

Comment: to suggest possible efficiencies that could be introduced, you would probably need to add all conditions to your question.

Comment: @user1063287 just did that, thanks

Comment: fyi, the first two conditions are the same, perhaps you want to edit that?  `!req.query.itemCode || !req.query.itemCode`.  just so people can give more relevant answers.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a specific function that return a bool and call this function in your if statement, this is the proper way because if somewhere else you need to do the same check you will call the function and avoid code duplication. Plus you can iterate over the req.query to check Null values

```
for (var propName in req.query) {
    if (req.query.hasOwnProperty(propName)) {
        If (!req.query[propName]) { return false: }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make a local reference to query to shorten it a tiny bit but ultimately that's pretty much the best way to do it. I might also divide it by line breaks for readability.

```
let query = req.query;

if (!query.itemCode 
    || !query.itemCode 
    || !query.totalQuantity 
    || !query.availableQuantity 
    || !query.quantityRequested 
    || !query.requestor 
    || !query.projectNum 
    || !query.projectDetails) 
return;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a helper function that takes an array of names, and checks each of those:

```
 const exists = (obj, ...keys) => {
   for(const key of keys)
     if(!obj[key]) throw new Error(`$key} is missing!`);
 };

 exists(req, "itemCode", /*...*/)
```

I assume its inside a Express handler, in that case add an error route to then send the error to the client.

Or, you could even create a middleware:

```
 const exists = (...keys) => (req, res, next) => {
   for(const key of keys) {
      if(!req.query[key])
       return res.status(500).send(`${key} is missing`);
   }
   next(); // all fine, go on
};

app.get("/stuff", exists("itemCode", /*...*/), (req, res) => {
  //...
});
```

---

For those who may be new to using the [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) syntax:

> The **rest parameter** syntax allows us to represent an indefinite number of arguments as an array.

```js
function myFun(a, b, ...manyMoreArgs) {
  console.log("a", a); 
  console.log("b", b);
  console.log("manyMoreArgs", manyMoreArgs); 
}

myFun("one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six");

// Console Output:
// a, one
// b, two
// manyMoreArgs, [three, four, five, six]
```

Given this syntax produces an array, we can then iterate over that with a [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) statement, eg:

```js
function myFun(a, b, ...manyMoreArgs) {
  console.log("a", a); 
  console.log("b", b);
  for (let value of manyMoreArgs) {
    console.log(value);
  }
}

myFun("one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six");

// Console Output:
// a, one
// b, two
// three
// four
// five
// six
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily write a little helper function for that. For example, you can hand over the object for which you want to make sure certain properties are set (`req.query` in your case), plus a list of properties that need to be set.

```js
function areAllPropertiesSet(obj, props) {
    for (const prop of props) {
        if (!obj[prop]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

const req = {
    query: {
        'param1': 'bla',
        'param2': 'blubb',
        'param3': 'hi'
    }
};

console.log(areAllPropertiesSet(req.query, ['param1', 'param2', 'param3']) === true);
console.log(areAllPropertiesSet(req.query, ['param1', 'param2', 'param3', 'param4']) === false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Object.values()` on `req.query` to get an array of all values.  Then, send those values through `array.some` to make sure they all exist.

```
const arr = Object.values(req.query);
const hasEmptyKey = arr.some(val => !val);
```

This assumes `req.query` has all the keys even if they're not filled out.  If that's not the case, you can check for length:

```
const numExpectedKeys = 10;
const arr = Object.values(req.query);
const hasEmptyKey = arr.length == numExpectedKeys && arr.some(val => !val);
```

or even explicitly destructure every key you expect to be present:

```
const { query: { itemCode, totalQty, availQty, otherPropYouCareAbout } } = req;
const arr = [itemCode, totalQty, availQty, otherPropYouCareAbout];
...
```